# Count up Timer using javascript and Jquery need to add years and / or more day digits -- Have Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really need some help on this one! I have the code pretty close from a tutorial and I have it formatted perfectly but I have it counting up from April 9th, 2009 which would be roughly 1425 Days or 3 Years 10months 23 days, I really would like some help rewriting the attached code to 'Years / Months / Days' and removing the minutes and seconds

Any Help would be greatly GREATLY appreciated!

```
 (function($){

// Number of seconds in every time division
var days    = 24*60*60,
    hours   = 60*60,
    minutes = 60;

// Creating the plugin
$.fn.countup = function(prop){

    var options = $.extend({
        callback    : function(){},
        start       : new Date()
    },prop);

    var passed = 0, d, h, m, s, 
        positions;

    // Initialize the plugin
    init(this, options);

    positions = this.find('.position');

    (function tick(){

        passed = Math.floor((new Date() - options.start) / 1000);

        // Number of days passed
        d = Math.floor(passed / days);
        updateDuo(0, 1, d);
        passed -= d*days;

        // Number of hours left
        h = Math.floor(passed / hours);
        updateDuo(2, 3, h);
        passed -= h*hours;

        // Number of minutes left
        m = Math.floor(passed / minutes);
        updateDuo(4, 5, m);
        passed -= m*minutes;

        // Number of seconds left
        s = passed;
        updateDuo(6, 7, s);

        // Calling an optional user supplied callback
        options.callback(d, h, m, s);

        // Scheduling another call of this function in 1s
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    })();

    // This function updates two digit positions at once
    function updateDuo(minor,major,value){
        switchDigit(positions.eq(minor),Math.floor(value/10)%10);
        switchDigit(positions.eq(major),value%10);
    }

    return this;
};


function init(elem, options){
    elem.addClass('countdownHolder');

    // Creating the markup inside the container
    $.each(['Days','Hours','Minutes','Seconds'],function(i){
        $('<span class="count'+this+'">').html(
            '<span class="position">\
                <span class="digit static">0</span>\
            </span>\
            <span class="position">\
                <span class="digit static">0</span>\
            </span>'
        ).appendTo(elem);

        if(this!="Seconds"){
            elem.append('<span class="countDiv countDiv'+i+'"></span>');
        }
    });

}

// Creates an animated transition between the two numbers
function switchDigit(position,number){

    var digit = position.find('.digit')

    if(digit.is(':animated')){
        return false;
    }

    if(position.data('digit') == number){
        // We are already showing this number
        return false;
    }

    position.data('digit', number);

    var replacement = $('<span>',{
        'class':'digit',
        css:{
            top:'-2.1em',
            opacity:0
        },
        html:number
    });

    // The .static class is added when the animation
    // completes. This makes it run smoother.

    digit
        .before(replacement)
        .removeClass('static')
        .animate({top:'2.5em',opacity:0},'fast',function(){
            digit.remove();
        })

    replacement
        .delay(100)
        .animate({top:0,opacity:1},'fast',function(){
            replacement.addClass('static');
        });
}
```

})(jQuery);

```
$(function(){

$('#countdown').countup({
start: new Date(2009, 04, 09, 15, 58, 21) //year, month, day, hour, min, sec
```

});

});

Comment: Please try reducing your code to just the bare essential so more people can help. Code dumps are rarely useful.

Comment: I dont know what the bare essential is... :( im sorry, I dont know any java at all, I'll remove what i can though

Comment: I think that cut it down quite a bit, sorry, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: That's better. The idea though is to debug, find and separate the piece of code that's giving you problems and try to reproduce the problem in isolation, preferably using jsFiddle or JSBin to test it.

Comment: yea... :/ sorry man im not familiar enough with java to even begin to try and fix this... although its not really a problem more I just need to know how to add a year formula and remove the others... for someone who knows java i feel like it would be a walk in the park... i got the code from here http://tutorialzine.com/2012/09/count-up-jquery/